# Symfony2 and Doctrine: complex relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my project I have entities `News`, `Articles` and `Comments`.
Users can add comments both to articles and news. Each user can add a few comments for each article or new.
I want have single `Comments` entity with composite key for relationships with `News` and `Articles` like

`subj_type` (news or articles) + `subj_id` (id of new or article)

Can I organize relationships by this way? Or I must organize two different Comments entities (like `NewsComments` and `ArticlesComments`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Inheritance Mapping and organize three Entities - Comments,NewsComments and ArticleComments by using Single Table Inheritance:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"news" = "NewsComments", "article" = "ArticleComments"})
 */
class Comments
{
    protected $type;
    protected $doc_id;
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class News extends ArticleComments
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class News extends NewsComments
{
    // ...
}
```

NewsComments and ArticleComments entities will contain (for exmaple) doc_id. In doc_id you will store News or Article Id.
And when will you get Comments for News through NewsComments repository, your will get Comments for News only.

[Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)